# A question about definition of Subobject

Tags: category-theory

The definition in which i refer is the article of wikipedia. My question is: the 2 monomorphisms belong in the category?

Comment: What wikipedia article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the monomorphisms are in the category you're working in. Remember that morphisms exist *in a category* - so unless otherwise specified, all morphisms referenced are morphisms *in the category you're living in*.